# Mosquitto MQTT - SSL/TLS and/or Username and Password Authentication

Tags: authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

I've asked a similar question on the MQTT forums but have not had any response:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1113220/

I have some devices that needs to authenticate with a certificate but does not have a username or password.
Then I have devices that needs to authenticate with a Username and Password but does not have a certificate.

It seems like when I enable username and password authentication, my devices with certificates cannot authenticate and when I define certificate paths, my devices without certificates, only a username and password, cannot authenticate

I'm not sure what is the correction configuration to achieve this or if it is even possible.

This is my current configuration:

```
listener 9993
per_listener_settings true
password_file pathtopasswordfile
require_certificate false
cafile pathtocafile
certfile pathtocertfile
keyfile pathtokeyfile
```

Comment: Just run 2 listeners on different ports

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1839#issuecomment-707656348) which confirms your analysis (on a single listener - as @hardillb says adding a second listener is an option).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from @hardillb and @Brits it seems like the Mosquitto broker does not allow this:

https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/1839#issuecomment-707656348

So the next best option will be to run two listeners on the same broker. Each listener having its own authentication configuration. I still need to verify that my message handler can subscribe to messages published from both types of devices. But I guess this should work since it is on the same broker.

Here is my working configuration:

```
# SSL/TLS with certificate authentication
listener port
use_identity_as_username true
require_certificate true
cafile pathtocafile
certfile pathtocertfile
keyfile pathtokeyfile

# Username and Password authentication
listener port
per_listener_settings true
password_file pathtopasswordfile
```

Comment: They is a single topic namespace, so messages publish one listener will be available to all clients regardless of which listener they contacted to